# Почему работает div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Есть код:

```html
<div id="div">текст</div>
<script>
  div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', '<p>Привет</p>');
  div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', '<p>Пока</p>');
</script>
```

Я не понимаю, почему простое выражение `div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', '<p>Пока</p>');` правильно работает.
Разве не нужно сначала с помощью getElementById() найти элемент с id = div, присвоить этот DOM  обьект переменной, а потом что-то в него вставлять.
Почему это работает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если элементу назначен специальный атрибут `id`, то можно получить его прямо по переменной с именем из значения `id`.

Это поведение соответствует **[стандарту](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-window-nameditem)**. Оно существует, в первую очередь, для совместимости, как осколок далёкого прошлого и не очень приветствуется, поскольку использует глобальные переменные. Браузер пытается помочь нам, смешивая пространства имён JS и DOM, но при этом возможны конфликты.

Но более **правильной** и **общепринятой** практикой является доступ к элементу вызовом `document.getElementById("идентификатор")`.